# Web service login to check authenticate user in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am writing a web service to authenticate whether a user login is valid or not. Below is a simple implementation of the web service placed inside UsersController.php

```
public function webservice_login() 
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {   
        if ($this->Auth->login()) 
        {
            echo json_encode(array('ok_msg' => 'User authentication success'));
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array('fail_msg' => 'User authentication failure'));
        }            
    } 
}
```

It does not work. The error message I received is something like this;

```
\n\tError: \n\tPostsController could not be found.

\n
\n\tError: \n\tCreate the class PostsController below in file: app\\Controller\\PostsController.php

\n
\n<?php\nclass PostsController extends AppController {\n\n}\n
\n
\n\tNotice: \n\tIf you want to customize this error message, create app\\View\\Errors\\missing_controller.ctp
```

What is wrong with the code? How should I rewrite the web service? I am using Cakephp 2.5. Strange thing is I do not have a controller called Post in the first place.

Comment: Can you send the request url you are getting error?

Comment: You do not have a controller posts ?? What is your controller then ? Have you used $this->Auth->allow() for the function where webservice_login is present

Comment: Show the URL you're calling.

Comment: The URL is 127.0.0.1/cakephp25/users/webservice_login/

Comment: can you visit the same url with your browser, have you used $this->Auth->allow('webservice_login'); in beforeFilter

Answer (score 1):

The error is *very* clear, just read the error message:

> \n\tError: \n\tPostsController could not be found.

Make sure your controller exists.

Also the way you implement the JSON response isn't very CakePHP'ish. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html how to do it better.

And I would recommend you to use [JSEND](http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend) as response format to communicate states.

Comment: there is no issue with t it is actually \t which represents tab space, i think it should be other reason

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using Short hand php tag:

This error may be due to use of short php tag i.e. `"<? ?>"`.

I recommend you to use `"<?php ?>"`.